# Install R package without biocmanager

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, bioconductor

I am using bioconductor image in order to install R packages. The problem I am facing is that I can't install specific version of the package.
I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM bioconductor/bioconductor_docker:bioc2020

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('ggplot2')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('DESeq2')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('RColorBrewer')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('ggrepel')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('factoextra')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('FactoMineR')"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('apeglm')"
```

The installation of `DESeq2` failed because for `locfit` package R version>4.1.0 is required. I want to install previous version of `locfit`, but it seems that I can't because even if I used the following command:

```
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('locfit', version='1.5-9.4')"
```

It actually use BiocManager.

Any help will be useful!

Comment: `install.packages` doesn't have a `version=` parameter. If you want to install specific versions, `devtools` might help `install_version("locfit", version = "1.5-9.4", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` More info here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Comment: @MrFlick Do you know if it's possible to have ```devtools``` and ```BiocManager``` in the same image? Doesn't ```BiocManager``` override it?